# Erlang: how to find a sub-tuple inside tuple

Tags: search, erlang, key-value

I use jsonerl to decode the request body in my app. the resulting tuple looks like this:

```
{
    {<<"message">>,<<"Hello World">>},             
    {<<"users">>, [
        {
            {<<"first_name">>,<<"Jules">>},
            {<<"last_name">>,<<"Winfield">>},
            {<<"id">>,1}
        },
        {
            {<<"first_name">>,<<"Vincent">>},
            {<<"last_name">>,<<"Vega">>},
            {<<"id">>,2}
        }
    ]},
    {<<"activities">>, [
        {
            {<<"type">>,<<"fetching bag">>},
            {<<"user_id">>,1}
        },
        {
            {<<"type">>,<<"discussing metrical system">>},
            {<<"user_id">>,2}
        }
    ]},
}
```

Of course the order of the subtuples is unknown.

I would like to hand over the user list to a function to create a record list. how can I get access to this list inside these tuples.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
{_, ListOfUsers} = lists:keyfind(<<"users">>, 1, tuple_to_list(YourListOfUsers)).
```

Answer (score 1):

You mean something like this with pattern matching?

```
{ _ , { _ , ListOfUsers } } = YourListOfUsers.
```

But if you mean by:

> Of course the order of the subtupels is unknown.

Is that users tuples sometimes appears first, then the previous snippet wont works. You should enforce some kind of structure in your result tuple.

Comment: In the example above it works, but in my case the users tupel is not the only with a list behind. I will edit my question regarding this.

Comment: @Stoecki So sometimes users tuple is after activities tuple?

Comment: yes, this depends on the serialization of different apps. so we cannot assume, that the order is fixed

Comment: @Stoecki Well that is difficult. You should enforce some kind of known order to to use a key-value data structure. Maps data structures in Erlang are the best use for JSON but it is available in R17.

Comment: lets assume the incoming request has a json like above (just switch the binaries to json keys like this: {<<"first_name">>,<<"Jules">>} becones {"first_name":"Jules"}). how would you create records from this (so one list of records for users, one for activities)? maybe you can point me here to the right direction. thanks in advance